# how to check if a motherboard support Multiple-GPU?

Tags: cuda, hardware, gpu, nvidia, multi-gpu

I'll be working on a research project with the integrated use of multiple GPUs. I'm thinking of setting up a Desktop with multiple GPU first.

I currently have a [MSI P55 CD53 motherboard](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/P55-CD53.html#/?div=Detail), with Intel I5-570 CPU and Nvidia GTS 250 GPU. I want to buy at least another 2 Nvidia Graphic Card to add to my existing desktop.

Is there any resource I can lookup, so that I can know if it's feasible to do, and what Graphic Card I should buy?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not look at Amazon's EC2 GPU offerings?  I needed to try out a multiple GPU setup, and got one up and running to test for a few evenings without having to shell out for two Tesla GPUs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification you linked indicates:

> • 1 PCI Express gen2 x16 slots

That means it can only accommodate one PCI Express GPU at a time.  So it's not feasible to run more than one GPU on that motherboard.

Questions like this are probably better suited to other forums like superuser.

Comment: Hi pls forgive me if I'm asking something sily... what does it mean by "1 PCI Express gen2 x16 slots" and "3 PCI Express gen2 x1 slots"? what's the meaning of *16 slots? or where I can get related information on these kind of terminology?

Comment: Well, when I used google, I got [this](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Everything-You-Need-to-Know-About-the-PCI-Express/190/4).

Comment: IC Thx. Hmm.. I also tried doing google but don't know what keyword to put. Google is more friendly to you I guess ;)

Comment: Additionally... do you think it's feasible to install an PCI-E X1 Graphic Card referring to: http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/pc-upgrades/3360487/can-i-use-pci-express-x1-slot-for-graphics-card/

Comment: It may be possible to do.  I wouldn't recommend it.